# How to open a form in same window in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am learning c# WPF application.
I have a menu which has a dropdown list. In the dropdown there are 3 other items.
Now on clicking an item i want to display the form in the same window.

What i did is that i have created a new wpf form and navigated it from the previous page.
But now i want to open it in the same page itself.

Please help

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel Height="43" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="dockPanel1"
               VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Menu Height="47" Name="menu1" Width="Auto" DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <MenuItem Header="_Entry Form" >
                <MenuItem Header="_Student Details" Name="studentDetails" Click="studentDetails_Click_1"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Faculty Details" Name="facultyDetails" />
                <Separator/>
                <MenuItem Header="E_xit" Name="exit" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
```

CS

```
 private void studentDetails_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // to navigate to a new page
        Student std = new Student();
        this.Close();
        std.Show();


    }
```

Now i donot want to navigate just display the student page in the same window

Comment: @GrowWithWPF Can u please change my code and help

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you'll need to add XAML that represents the `Student` class, probably a bunch of [`TextBoxes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx), wrapped in some kind of container, like a `Border`, `Grid`, or `StackPanel`, and set the `Visibility` property of the container to `Collapsed`.

When the button is then clicked, you can populate the text boxes (or other UI elements) with the appropriate `Student` parameters, then set the container's `Visibility` property to `Visible`.

I would really recommend you check out the Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) pattern, though. There is a bit of a learning curve, but it's well worth the investment.

Comment: So how to start with this. I have started Visual studio just from today

Comment: I guess [this WPF/MVVM tutorial on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial) would be a good starting point.